# Procurar valor de Array em Objeto

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho seguinte Objecto:

```
let Filmes = [{
                "Nome": "Harry Potter 1",
                "Preco": "50"
             },
             {
                "Nome": "Harry Potter 2",
                "Preco": "60"
             },
             {
                "Nome": "Harry Potter 3",
                "Preco": "70"
             }] 

let Cliente = ["Harry Potter 1", "Harry Potter 3"]
let ValorFinal = ""
```

Como eu faço usando o array `Cliente` para verificar em quais `Filmes`  o `Cliente` quer? E após fazer isso, me retornar o `Preco` do filme. O output disto seria:

> Valor final = 120

Porque o Cliente quer o `Harry Potter 1` e `Harry Potter 3`.

*Se possível em vanilla JS por favor*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É possível usar os métodos [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) e [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
let filmes = [{
                "Nome": "Harry Potter 1",
                "Preco": "50"
             },
             {
                "Nome": "Harry Potter 2",
                "Preco": "60"
             },
             {
                "Nome": "Harry Potter 3",
                "Preco": "70"
             }];

let cliente = ["Harry Potter 1", "Harry Potter 3"];

const valor = filmes.filter((f) => cliente.includes(f.Nome)) // Filtra pelos escolhidos
    .reduce((a, b) => a + parseFloat(b.Preco), 0); // Soma o valor dos escolhidos

console.log(valor);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Esses metodos de Filter, Reduce e Map são meio complicados. Mas são extremamente úteis!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esta iteração trará o resultado esperado:

```
var valorFinal = 0;

for (i = 0; i < Filmes.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Cliente.length; j++) {
        if (Cliente[j] == Filmes[i]["Nome"]) {
            valorFinal += Filmes[i]["Preco];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Este funciona perfeitamente também, mas optei pela outra resposta por ser mais fácil de ler :) . Obrigado!